# OptionsMenu not displayed in activity?

Tags: android, android-layout

I try to add an optionsMenu to my activity. I use the code from the android.developer guide :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/new_game"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_new_game"
          android:title="@string/new_game" />
    <item android:id="@+id/help"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
          android:title="@string/help" />
</menu>
```

and

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

I use the same code in two different activities, but only in one of them the optionsmenu is displayed... posting the whole activity code wouldnt make sense, so please comment if special code segments are helpful. I hope anyone can help me! THX

EDIT: I already found the problem : I overrode onKeyDown(..) and returned true at the end, so other key-related events have not been called...

Comment: You can use [this](http://androidforums.com/developer-101/197383-same-menu-different-activities.html) concept.

Comment: thanks for the idea, but I only need the options in one activity. The other was just for testing reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue once and I got rid off by not using the string resource but placing menu name directly in title....Check if it works for you too or not....